# Om.next: apply vs directly passing children

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript, om

In the [Om.next wiki](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Components,-Identity-&-Normalization), there is example code like this (code listing at the bottom of the linked page):

```
(apply dom/ul nil
    (map person list))
```

Since `dom/ul` takes a variable number of arguments, what is the benefit of using `apply` vs this:

```
(dom/ul nil (map person list))
```

This second approach seems more analogous to passing an array as `children` in vanilla React, which is supported.

Actual question (response to comment): Is `apply` necessary? If so, why doesn't the latter approach work? If not, what benefit is gained from using `apply` like in the example?

Comment: are you asking why `apply` is necessary? Or why they defined the api such that apply is necessary? Or something else?

Comment: Hey @ez121sl — I updated the question to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ClojureScript signature of `dom/ul` is apparently something like `(defn ul [attrs & children] ...)`. Here `children` is a vararg. The caller can pass in 0 or more children. Therefore, the following invocations are valid:

```
(dom/ul nil (person jack))
(dom/ul nil (person jack) (person jill))
(dom/ul nil)
```

Now suppose you have a collection of elements that you'd like to wrap in a ul. The collection maybe comes from `(map person list)`, which returns a sequence of elements. If ul is invoked like `(dom/ul nil (map person list))`, only a single child argument is passed to `ul`, and it is of the wrong type. Each child is expected to be an element, but a collection of element is passed in instead.

`apply` to the rescue. The job of `apply` is deal with the situation where we have a collection of arguments, which must be passed in individually. So, `(dom/ul nil (person jack) (person jill))` is equivalent to `(apply dom/ul nil (map person [jack jill]))`. `apply` is necessary in this case to make sure the arguments are passed to `ul` as that function is expecting them. Skipping `apply` is not an option.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was thrown off because in vanilla React, multiple `children` are specified as a single array. Currently appears that, because of that, either approach works in this case

Answer (score 1):

In Lisp you can't pass a list or collection in place of individual variadic arguments and expect the same behavior.

If you do so anyway, the collection argument will be interpreted as a first of all variadic arguments.  To spread a collection as function arguments, you have to use `apply`.